# How to resolve Framework not found JitsiMeetSDK.xcframework error

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, jitsi-meet, lib-jitsi-meet

I want to integrate JitsiMeetSDK framework for iOS project. but it gives me error:

```
ld: framework not found JitsiMeetSDK.xcframework
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have set all the info as per link : https://jitsi.github.io/handbook/docs/dev-guide/dev-guide-ios-sdk

I have used cocoapods, Xcode 12.4, Swift project. Any suggestions?

Comment: I am also facing the same issues, does anyone have any solution to this? I am using this JITSI sample code https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet-sdk-samples

Comment: I am able to resolve it by upgrading Cocoapod version installed on my mac using "sudo gem install cocoapods"